# C++: explicitly tell the scheduler the level of cohesion of threads in portable code

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, scheduler

In standard C++, can I group dependent threads together, so the scheduler can avoid assignment of those threads off a single CCX in Zen architecture?

Due to drawback of slow inter-CCX communication speed in Zen architecture, I would like to group threads as described. Are there some kind of ISO C++ methodologies that I can keep threads that are dependent on one another in group so the scheduler can avoid putting them off a CCX?

In other words, how can I explicitly tell the scheduler the level of cohesion of threads in portable code.